# Can we remove active directory Completely from Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, trusted-identity-provider

I need to know , can we remove active directory completely from SharePoint . Is there any alternate option for Active Directory (identity directory) in SharePoint ? If yes then What will be pros and cons of using other identity directory ?

Comment: What u mean by removing AD from SharePoint? If you have problem with using AD in SharePoint, then you can using **Form Based Authentication**

Comment: Removing AD means using an alternate like Apache Directory in SharePoint for authentication and identity management